# Issue with statistical test

Tags: r, statistics

I use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to test for normality in a sample. For example, when I do

```
x <- rnorm(1e4, 10, 5)
ks.test(x, "pnorm")
```

I get the following result:

```
D = 0.4556, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The p-value is almost 0. But I cannot understand why because the test should accept null hypothesis....

Comment: The KS does *not* test for normality! Have a look at the Anderson-Darling or Shapiro-Wilk tests instead.

Comment: On a different (but conceptually more important) note, you should try to understand why you're getting the result above. What are you testing? What is your null hypothesis?

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless and https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TeachingDemos/versions/2.10/topics/SnowsPenultimateNormalityTest

Comment: @Pop Yes I tend to agree with you; to slightly go back on what I said before, actually all three tests (KS, AD, SW) are being used as tests for normality, see e.g. [Razali and Wah, Journal of Statistical Modelling and Analytics 2, 21 (2011)](http://www.de.ufpb.br/~ulisses/disciplinas/normality_tests_comparison.pdf). So one could argue that the AD test is as much a normality test as the SW test. *Empirically*, the later seems to have the greatest power.

Comment: Totally agree. That's why I retracted my comment a few minutes before ;)

Comment: Great. +1 for your answer and explanations below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for normality with the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, as it is a goodness of fit test. However, (as pointed out by Maurits Evers in comments) more specific test like [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) would be more suited.

When you want to compare the distribution of a sample `x` to a theoretical distribution as `pnorm`, you need to give the **parameters** of this distribution. In this cas, the mean and standard variation.

Here's what you should have:

```
ks.test(x, "pnorm", 10, 5)
```

**EDIT:**

An example of how to use Shapiro-Wilk test (from `stats` package, too) in this case, as its power is greater than KS's one:

```
shapiro.test(x)
```

Note that in this implementation, the length of `x` must be between 3 and 5000.